# Using a point as an input for a perceptron

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, perceptron, neural-computing

Can a point be used as the input for a perceptron/neural net?

The relationship between the two numbers that make up a 2D point does not affect the output, but does this not matter when the satisfactory weights are found?

If I wanted to use a point $(x,y)$ as an input for my perceptron, would I simply have two input nodes, one for $x$ and one for $y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  Nothing prevents it.  Yes, you'd have two inputs, one for $x$ and one for $y$.  You might want to normalize those values so they are in the range $[-1,1]$ or $[0,1]$.